# Best Practice/Better Performance - Azure Data Factory and SQL Views

Tags: azure-data-factory, sql-view

I have about 10 tables that I use to create a SQL view. Some of these are pure lookup tables. And there are some SELECT clause columns that use Concatenation and other basic functions.
The data volume is expected to be about ~ 2 million rows.
I need to use the data from the SQL view to load into final tables using Azure Data Factory data flow.

Now I am just wondering if I should remove the lookup part from the view and add that to ADF flow. And also for the concatenation and simple functions in SELECTed columns in the view, I think I should maybe use Derived Column transformation in the data flow.

Just trying to understand what would the best practice be. And also, in terms of performance which one would be better?

Is it better to perform the required transformations and lookups in the view? That way the source data would be available in the required format and flow would be faster because not much transformation would be processed.

But if I have to make all the lookups and transformations in SQL view itself then what is the benefit of using a ETL tool like ADF?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you keep it all in the SQL and use a standard ADF data copy. It's easier to troubleshoot if you can log on to the SQL Server and run a view, vs, digging through transformations in an ETL tool.

the copy activity doesn't support any transformation but ADF data flows do.

However, ADF data flows have to spin up a databricks instance to do anything and that can take up to five minutes

*what is the benefit of using a ETL tool like ADF*

When you write your transformations in SQL you end up with a mass of code that can sometimes be difficult to maintain and audit

When you write your transformations in an ETL tool, you often get useful plumbing like logging and lineage and debugging. Also an ETL tool can more easily span multiple data sources, i.e. it can combine a text file with a database table.

Some people also prefer the visual aspect of ETL tools.

Many ETL tools also come with out of the box templates/wizards that assist in mundane tasks.